# Twig (or Symfony?) doesn't run my jQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, twig, symfony4

I currently am trying to create a website using Symfony 4. The issue is that one of my pages is in need of a jQuery script to work, part of it is working but functions like these aren't called, why ?

Example of code not being called :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".someClass").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".active.focused").toggleClass("active");
        $(".focused").toggleClass("focused");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(this).toggleClass("focused");
        refresh_contents();  //this is another external function that I don't
                             //manage to call, even  when called in the 
                             //executed part
    });
});
```

I am sure it doesn't come from my javascript as I tested it "off-symfony".
Thanks in advance, Crikripex

Comment: As you're new here, please take some time to review [ask].

Comment: You would need to move your Javascript into the footer of your HTML document for element level events to execute outside of `$(document).ready()`. When the Javascript is in the head, the elements do not yet exist in the DOM for Javascript to find the referenced selector. See: https://jsfiddle.net/8tqw5rrz/

Comment: Thanks for your answers, i took some time to ask my question differently and to be more precise in my code.
Now that I moved the javascript in the footer I no longer have the ``refresh_contents() is not a function`` error, but it still doesn't execute (nor enter in the function)

Comment: I've tried to console out the elements where the onclick is supposed to apply but it apparently displays objects with 0 of lengh when it should display DOM elements with parameters. Can anyone help me?
@fyrye

Comment: Are you using Webpack Encore? What does `window.console.log($)` display? Are there any errors in the console? Please post the rendered page HTML.

Comment: @fyrye I am using Webpack Encore, do you think using Assetics could solve the issue?
There are no errors in the console and console.log($) displays ``> function jQuery`` with the same functions inside as when i do it off-symfony.
My html looks like this : https://pastebin.com/vXzcrAnM
If you want to try out my script, here it is : https://pastebin.com/SKJa5zmy
One strange thing is that using browser's console, I manage to manually change the DOM off-symfony, but it stops working when i switch to symfony

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so after hours trying to figure out what and where the issue is, I came to the conclusion (thanks to @fyrye) that there might be compatibility issues between jQuery and Symfony4 or Webpack Encore.
I then decided to "translate" my code from jQuery to Javascript without any library and it worked fine.
To summarize, I went from :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".someClass").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".active.focused").toggleClass("active");
        $(".focused").toggleClass("focused");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(this).toggleClass("focused");
        refresh_contents();  
    });
});
```

to :

```
for(i=0;i<maxId;i++){
    document.getElementById("contain_" + i).onclick = function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            document.getElementsByClassName("focused")[0].classList.remove("active");
            document.getElementsByClassName("focused")[0].classList.remove("focused");
            document.getElementById(this.id).classList.add("active");
            document.getElementById(this.id).classList.add("focused");
            refresh_contents();
        }
}
```

I know it doesn't look as fancy, it's not as easy to code as jQuery, but so far that's the only solution I found that actually works.

Thanks for your help everybody.

Comment: I believe if you update your question to include your `webpack.config.js` we can help you resolve the issue. Using Webpack Encore requires the use of ECMAScript 6/nodejs constructs in order to `export` and `import` the variables to the scripts you use, since they are no longer available as a `global var`. I suggest watching the KNPUniversity tutorial on using [WebPack Encore](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/webpack-encore) as it is a steep learning curve on how you are required to write Javascript in webpack as opposed to vanilla.

Comment: Looking at the source code in comparison to your selectors, they do not match what is in the dom. e.g. `.list-group-item.list-group-item-action.mobilePart` does not exist, where `.mobilePart .list-group-item.list-group-item-action` would be the equivalent.